# sed + append new lines after matched word but ignore if lines are exists

Tags: sed

we create the follwinmg sed line in order to add the lines after mached word  ( on redhat 7.x machines )

```
sed -i '/\[Service\]/a MemoryAccounting=yes\nMemoryCurrent=8192000\nMemoryLimit=8192000' /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
```

example of the file before update

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
[Unit]
Description=System Logging Service
;Requires=syslog.socket
Wants=network.target network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Documentation=man:rsyslogd(8)
Documentation=http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n $SYSLOGD_OPTIONS
Restart=on-failure
UMask=0066
StandardOutput=null
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
;Alias=syslog.service
```

example of the file after the update by sed

```
cat /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
[Unit]
Description=System Logging Service
;Requires=syslog.socket
Wants=network.target network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Documentation=man:rsyslogd(8)
Documentation=http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/

[Service]
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryCurrent=8192000
MemoryLimit=8192000
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n $SYSLOGD_OPTIONS
Restart=on-failure
UMask=0066
StandardOutput=null
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
;Alias=syslog.service
```

now the problem is when we run again the sed line then we get duplicate lines as

```
[Service]
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryCurrent=8192000
MemoryLimit=8192000
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryCurrent=8192000
MemoryLimit=8192000
```

any suggestion how to ignore editing when the lines are already exists ?

notes:

in order to complete service update we need to do the following:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart rsyslog.service
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
sed -i.SAVED '/\[Service\]/N;
s/\n/ /;
/\[Service\] Type=notify/c\
[Service]\
MemoryAccounting=yes\
MemoryCurrent=8192000\
MemoryLimit=8192000\
Type=notify

/\[Service\] M.*/s/ /\n/
' /lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service
```

it's joining lines using `N`, replacing the `nl` with space checking if it matches the original line.

Also saving the original file just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Eei.bak '/\[service]/I{n;/^memoryaccounting/I!{i MemoryAccounting=yes\nMemoryCurrent=8192000\nMemoryLimit=8192000' -e '}}' input_file
[Unit]
Description=System Logging Service
;Requires=syslog.socket
Wants=network.target network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
Documentation=man:rsyslogd(8)
Documentation=http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/

[Service]
MemoryAccounting=yes
MemoryCurrent=8192000
MemoryLimit=8192000
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/rsyslog
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n $SYSLOGD_OPTIONS
Restart=on-failure
UMask=0066
StandardOutput=null
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
;Alias=syslog.service
```

Answer (score 1):

This `sed` command will skip the insertion of text if the `[Service]` is immediately followed by a line starting with `MemoryAccounting=`.

```
sed -i.orig '
/\[Service]/{
n
/^MemoryAccounting=/b
i\
MemoryAccounting=yes\
MemoryCurrent=8192000\
MemoryLimit=8192000
}' rsyslog.service
```